# Poly-time approximation scheme for problems with pseudo-polynomial time algorithms

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, approximation-algorithms

The question is: Does a poly-time approximation scheme always exist for NP-complete problems that have pseudo-polynomial time algorithms (like knapsack for example)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is NO. Petra Schuurman and Gerhard Woeginger have written about this in their [tutorial](http://www.win.tue.nl/~gwoegi/papers/ptas.pdf). See Example 0.6.3 on p.46 in their paper when there's no FPTAS while problem has pseudopolynomial algorithm. What concerns an example when there's no PTAS while problem has pseudopolynomial algorithm I suggest Binary Paint Shop Problem (discussed also [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4110/partitioning-a-segmented-stick), definition can be found in the first answer).

Also there is good picture in tutorial on p.5 on relations between approximation classes and Pseudo-Polynomial Time.

Answer (score 5):

It depends. Gerhard Woeginger has a paper on a related problem: [when a dynamic programming formulation of a problem leads to a PTAS](http://www.win.tue.nl/~gwoegi/papers/fptas.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

You should look at Sect. 2.4. of [Giorgio Ausiello, Pierluigi Crescenzi, Marco Protasi: Approximate Solution of NP Optimization Problems. Theor. Comput. Sci. 150(1): 1-55 (1995)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975%2894%2900291-P).

They prove how pseudo-polynomial algorithms and FPTASs (that is PTASs whose time complexity is polynomial in $1/\epsilon$) are related.